# split lines in huge text file containing messy user entries with python

Tags: python, string, split

I have a huge text file. Using python, I'm trying to extract some relevant information and save it into a CSV. The line delimiters are brackets (), and each line is split into different entries, delimited by commas(,). The problem arises is that some of the entries are strings with user text, which can contain brackets and commas. Therefore, the usual split methods can't work here.
Example:

```
(1,2,3,"hello world, I "love" you(sometimes)",5,"manchester united"),(4,5,6,"mary poppins",7,"spoon full of sugar("),
```

I need to split the text into users/lines based on the (), and then
I should be able to split the line into entries. For example, the first user entries are as follows:

- `user1[1]` - `1`
- `user1[2]` - `2`
- `user1[3]` - `3`
- `user1[4]` - `"hello world, I "love" you(sometimes)"`
- `user1[5]` - `5`
- `user1[6]` - `"manchester united"`

I'm stuck! thanks all

Comment: This doesn't seem like a parsable format. How do you know which quotes are delimiters around the string versus quotes that are inside strings?

Comment: Yes I agree. The file is originally in sql format. I thought there was a way to handle it with python, but it's possible I can't do it...

Comment: It should be possible to simply flag a quote if it immediately follows a comma, otherwise treat it as a part of the string.

Comment: What do you mean by sql format? If you're fetching the data from a database, why don't you just extract them into separate variables rather than putting them into these unformatted strings?

Comment: @daShier That's possible, but what if the data actually contains quote-comma?

Comment: I think you should solve this problem at the source. It should use an established serialization format, such as JSON.

Comment: Very strange export format.  Typically, anything professional that was exporting data like this would have an escape sequence; so for example:
(1,2,3,"hello world, I \"love\" you(sometimes)",5,"manchester united"),(4,5,6,"mary poppins",7,"spoon full of sugar(\")

My question for you is -- how exactly are you receiving this data?  What product, and what API, and what method in that API, is returning this data?

Comment: If you yourself are the author who is EXPORTING the data, then let me suggest outputing the data with "repr(data)", and then importing the data with "ast.literal_eval(s)".

Comment: @Barmar As long as us mere humans can parse it, there should be a set of rules that allows an algorithm to be written. It might require a couple of flags to create a state machine for the comma and quotation delimiters. I'm assuming that the author of the OP has only the text file and no ability to reformat it from the source.

Comment: I don't think a human can parse this: `(1,2,3,"This string contains quote-comma-quote "," in the middle")` @daShier

Comment: The only reason you and I know that the comma in the middle isn't a delimiter is because the text says so. An algorithm to do this would require sophisticated AI.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that (hypothetical) string would certainly be parsed as two strings.

Comment: But if you're really stuck with this data format, you'll have to write a heuristic as @daShier suggests. There's no built-in way to do this, you'll have to write your own parser.